# Why is anything inside script tag not working in the ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have a post schema in Mongoose with a variable named `isReviewed`. Inside the unreviewedposts.ejs file I have a button, which makes `isReviewed = true` on click, so I have used script with click event listener, but on click nothing happens.

I know I can use AJAX request to a route, where I can easily change the variable's value, but wouldn't it be overhead to make a request just for changing a variable's value?

So I want to update the variable inside this script only so how can I do that?

Get route:-

```
router.get('/unreviewedposts', middleware.isAdmin, middleware.isAuditor, (req,res)=>{
 Post.find({}, (err,allposts)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else{
      res.render("unreviewedposts", {posts: allposts})
    }
  }) 
})
```

unreviewedposts.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>unreviewed posts of all the subjects are here </h1>
  <% if(currentUser !== null && currentUser.role === "admin" || currentUser.role === "auditor"){ %>
    <p><%=currentUser.username%> with <%=currentUser.role%> role is logged in!</p>
  <br><br><br>
  <% posts.forEach((post)=>{ %>
  <h1> <%=post.title%> </h1> 
  <h3> <%=post.publishDay%> <%=post.publish_date%> </h3>
  <h3>published by <%=post.author.username%></h3>
  <h4>this post is of <%=post.subject%></h4>

  <p><%-post.sanitizedHtml%> </p>
  <div>
    <span>Likes: <%=post.likes%></span>
    <span>Views: <%=post.views%></span>
  </div>
  <button id="approve">approve this post and send to respective posts page</button>
  <script>
    var approveButton = document.getElementById('approve');
    approveButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      <%=post.isReviewed%> = true;
      console.log(<%=post.isReviewed%>);
    })
  </script>
  <!-- here we put the operations on these posts by th admins or auditors -->
  <a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>/edit">Edit this post</a>
  <form action="/<%=post._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
    <button type="submit">Delete post</button>
  </form>
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <% }) %>
  <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a permanent change to data you're going to have to POST it, otherwise the change to `isReviewed` exists only in the local user's browser and will never be seen by anyone else, and lost once they reload / leave the page. Don't worry too much about overhead. It is pretty common to use exactly this method for updating data.

As for your actual code, assuming `post.isReviewed` is a boolean, you cannot do this line:

```
<%=post.isReviewed%> = true;
```

Because this will render to:

```
true = true;
```

Or:

```
false = true;
```

Which obviously isn't valid.

Instead you would have to do something like:

```
let postIsReviewed = <%=post.isReviewed%>;
```

And later modify that variable in the event handler.